# Nest.js: Global AuthGuard but with exceptions

Tags: nestjs

I would like to register my AuthenticationGuard, which checks for Authentication, globally on my application, so that by default all routes require authentication.

```
const authGuard = app
    .select(AuthModule)
    .get(AuthGuard);
app.useGlobalGuards(authGuard);
```

What is the best/nest.js way to add route exceptions, so that anonymous routes can also be implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Update**: See the upvoted answer below which is correct instead of mine (as I can't delete already accepted answer)

There is no way to configure such behavior in a succinct way. If `useGlobalGuards` used, the only way to do this is to customize or extend `AuthGuard`.

[See original issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/964#issuecomment-413563009)

Comment: One should probably look at the upvoted answer below (or above) by @jonathan002, instead of mine

Answer (score 47):

You can actually set metadata for the global `AuthGuard` so it can determine if it should allow an unauthorized request.

e.g.

Set Global Auth Guard

```js
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
    
    @Module({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_GUARD,
          useClass: AuthGuard,
        },
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Use `SetMetadata` to pass in data to the `AuthGuard`

```js
    import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
    // Convienience Function
    const AllowUnauthorizedRequest = () => SetMetadata('allowUnauthorizedRequest', true);
    @Controller()
    export class AppController {
    
      @Get('my-unauthorized-path')
      @AllowUnauthorizedRequest()
      myHandler () {
        return { unauthorized: true };
      }
    
    }
```

Use data passed in from `SetMetadata` to determine if unauthorized request is allowed.

```js
    import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { validateRequest } from './validateRequest' // your custom implementation
    
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    
      constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}
      canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const allowUnauthorizedRequest = this.reflector.get<boolean>('allowUnauthorizedRequest', context.getHandler());
        return allowUnauthorizedRequest || validateRequest(request);
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Just one thing to clarify, you can have the `AllowUnauthorizedRequest` decorator in a separate file (in a shared folder for example). Then, you just import and add `AllowUnauthorizedRequest` to the requests you want to exclude.

Comment: To make this work when set on controllers use `this.reflector.getAllAndOverride` and specify both `context.getHandler` as well as `context.getClass`; see docs https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context