# Should i use a global guard or different guards, the point is that i have a global guard and i need to exclude it for some request

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

i have implemented this guard which runs for every route but i need to exclude it for login or register.
how should i resolve this by best practice??

this are the routes:

```
 @SetMetadata('public', true)
  @Post('login')
  public async login(
    @Body('email') email: string,
    @Body('password') password: string,
  ): Promise<any> {

    return this.authService.loginUser(email, password);
  }


@SetMetadata('roles', ['admin'])
  @Get('allUser')
  public async getAll() {
    return await this.authService.getAllUsers();
  }
```

Guard example:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {

    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>("public",[context.getHandler(),context.getClass()]);
    const getHandler = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    console.log('---roles--as---isPublic--', isPublic);
    console.log('---roles--from getHandler--', getHandler);

    if (isPublic) {
      return true
    }

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const roles = request.user["roles"];

    console.log('---roles----', roles);

    if(roles === "guest" && typeof isPublic === "undefined"){
      return true
    } else{
      throw new UnauthorizedException()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nest.js: Global AuthGuard but with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429241/nest-js-global-authguard-but-with-exceptions)